# What does --hue mean in css?

Tags: css

css from a tutorial

[image]

I'm trying to understand this from a tutorial I'm watching on youtube, but I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `--hue` is a CSS variable.

The code `--hue: var(--hue-correct)` is setting the CSS variable `--hue` to the value of the variable `--hue-correct` (e.g. `145`)

For more information, see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp